# (.NET 8 Microsserviços) Como utilizar uma API IDENTITY da biblioteca Entity Framework com Ocelot?

Tags: c#, .net, autenticação, microsserviços, identity

Atualmente, estudando Ocelot e microsserviços com .NET 8
No momento, estou com dificuldades em proteger as rotas configuradas no Ocelot com um microsserviço de autenticação (Identity).
A ideia no geral, é primeiramente o usuário se autenticar na rota de autenticação e retornar um token Bearer do Identity.
Desse token, o usuário poderá acessar as outras rotas configuradas no Ocelot, segue o meu apiGateway.json:

```
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl":  "https://localhost:7097"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/orders/{everything}",
      "DownStreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7047
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/orderservices/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "IdentityApiKey",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }

    },
    
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/identity/{everything}",
      "DownStreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7112
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/identity/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note que a rota /gateway/orderservices/{everything} está configurada a Authenticação.
No meu Program.CS do Ocelot está configurado assim:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var authenticationProviderKey = "IdentityApiKey";
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("apiGateway.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(s =>
{
    s.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    s.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, x =>
{
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.Authority = "https://localhost:7112";
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false, 
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authenticationProviderKey))

    };
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddOcelot();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseOcelot().Wait();
app.Run();
```

no qual x.Authority = "https://localhost:7112" é onde está localizado o meu servidor de autenticação.

A rota /gateway/orderservices/{everything} está protegida, retornando 401 caso o token seja inválido, o problema é que mesmo que eu coloque um token valido, ainda continua retornando 401 (unauthorized)
Será que esqueci de configurar algo?

Segue o Program.cs do Identity:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TesteMicroServiços.Context;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<SqlServerContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connection));
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<SqlServerContext>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGroup("/identity").MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();


app.Run();
```